# Checking whether indexes are being used in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, phpmyadmin

I have two tables in my database that look roughly like this:

Movement:

```
Timestamp            visitorID Type        X   Y  
2012-03-02 11:02:30  379      pedestrian  32  46
2012-03-01 12:32:41  654      pedestrian  54  56
2012-03-02 07:02:16  789      pedestrian  39  52
```

Communication: (Calls made)

```
Timestamp            senderID     toID GeneralLocation 
2012-03-02 09:02:30  878          674        Grasslands 
2012-03-02 11:30:01  456          213        Tundra 
2012-03-02 07:02:12  789          654        Mountains
```

and I ran this query:

```
SELECT c.senderID,c.timestamp,m.timestamp,m.x,m.y
FROM communication c
JOIN movement m ON c.senderID = m.visitorID
WHERE m.timestamp = (SELECT MIN(mm.timestamp)
                 FROM movement mm 
                 WHERE mm.timestamp >= c.timestamp);
```

That basically finds the closest movement timestamp for a given communication timestamp. What I want to do is find the location at which a certain senderID placed a call. Since not every visitorID made a call, it first checks `c.senderID = m.visitorID`. So then it's goes through each row of `communication` and finds the closest `movement timestamp` for each `timestamp` in the `communication` table.

I then used `EXPLAIN` to see if I am using my indexes... and I got this:

[image]

Does that mean in the second row that my indexes are not being used correct? The indexes I have in place right now are:

```
CREATE INDEX timestamp ON DBName.movement (timestamp); 

CREATE INDEX ctstamp ON DBName.communication (timestamp);

CREATE INDEX SID_tstamp ON communication (senderID, timestamp);

CREATE INDEX VID_tstamp ON movement (visitorID, timestamp);
```

So basically, in the `Movement` and `Communication` tables, I have an index for each `timestamp`. And then I have one for each `ID` and `timestamp`.

My question basically is, what is wrong with my indexes, and how can I modify them so they can be used?

I'm new to SQL, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's using an index.  The `ref` and `keylen` tell us that.

I think you may be confused by the `Using index` in the Extra column of the other rows in the EXPLAIN output. That means that the query is being satisfied entirely from the index, without a need to visit the underlying data pages.

If you're concerned about performance, it's the correlated subquery we need to look at.  (The reference to `c.` in that subquery.)

**EDIT**

I'm thinking that your query should include a predicate on `mm.visitorID = c.senderID`  (that's based on the normative pattern we usually see in queries like this.

It looks like you want the position (`x`,`y`) at the earliest `timestamp` from `m` that's after the timestamp on `c`... and you've got a condition (predicate) that matches visitorID to senderID.  I think you want to repeat that same condition in the check for "earliest" timestamp.  (Otherwise, you could get a timestamp for some other visitorID)

Just that one change might speed up your query a bit, given a suitable index

... ON movement (vistorID, timestamp)

Actually including `x` and `y` in that index as well would let those values be returned from the index, and you'll get `Using index` in your EXPLAIN output.

---

Taking that change into account, here's a first cut at a re-write that avoids a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT c.senderID
     , c.timestamp
     , m.timestamp  AS m_timestamp
     , m.x
     , m.y
  FROM ( SELECT mc.senderID
              , mc.timestamp
              , MIN(mm.timestamp) AS min_timestamp
           FROM communication mc                    --< table alias mc
           JOIN movement mm                         --< table alias mm
             ON mm.visitorID  = mc.senderID
             ON mm.timestamp >= mc.timestamp
          GROUP BY mc.senderID, mc.timestamp
          ORDER BY mc.senderID, mc.timestamp
       ) r                                          --< table alias r
  JOIN movement m                                   --< table alias m
       ON  m.visitorID   = r.senderID
       AND m.timestamp   = r.min_timestamp
  JOIN communication c
       ON  c.senderID    = r.senderID
       AND c.timestamp   = r.timestamp
 ORDER BY r.senderID, r.timestamp
```

Here, the inline view (aliased as `r` is tasked with getting the earliest timestamp from `movement`).  That's going to spin the results into a "temporary" table. (I put temporary in quotes; it's temporary in that its around for the duration of the query, but it's called a **derived table** in the MySQL vernacular.)

There's a `GROUP BY` operation; hopefully, we can avoid a `Using filesort` operation and have that optimized using a suitable index.

Once we have that, it should just be index lookups into `c` and `m`.

---

I'm looking at this again. We don't actually need to do the join to `c`, we've already got the values from the inline view.

I say give this a rip, and let me know how big a smoke ball it makes. (No guarantees, because this isn't tested.)

```
  SELECT r.senderID
       , r.timestamp
       , m.timestamp AS m_timestamp
       , m.x
       , m.y
    FROM ( SELECT mc.senderID
                , mc.timestamp
                , MIN(mm.timestamp) AS min_timestamp
             FROM communication mc                     -- < table alias mc
             JOIN movement mm                          -- < table alias mm
               ON mm.visitorID  = mc.senderID
               ON mm.timestamp >= mc.timestamp
            GROUP BY mc.senderID, mc.timestamp
            ORDER BY mc.senderID, mc.timestamp
         ) r                                           -- < table alias r
    JOIN movement m                                    -- < table alias m
         ON  m.visitorID   = r.senderID
         AND m.timestamp   = r.min_timestamp
   ORDER BY r.senderID, r.timestamp
```

**EDIT** corrected invalid references `c.` to `mc.` in the previous two queries.

Comment: Ohh I see thanks a lot! So then it's the correlated subquery that's taking the most time? Is there any way I could reduce that past indexing then?

Comment: That correlated subquery gets run for every row from the outer query, see the `rows` estimate... that's not the number of rows in `mm`, that's an estimate of the number of rows that are going to be examined. I'm working to see if a re-write of your query is possible, (standby)

Comment: agreed. stay away from correlated like the plague

Comment: The `MIN(mm.timestamp)` ... you want to compare that to `c.timestamp` only, and not include `mm.visitorID = c.senderID` ? I apologize, I'm a little confused.  I don't see `senderID` or `visitorID` in the exemplar data. Is there a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY in either of the tables?

Comment: @spencer7593 Sorry, that was my mistake, I just fixed the column names.   Also, I have a list of communication timestamps for a set of ID's, and I have movement timestamps for the ID's as well. What I want to do is for a given communication timestamp, find the closest movement timestamp. Basically, I want to find where a call was made. For example, if I made a call at 1:10:01, and I have movement timestamp that says that I was at (54,32) at 1:10:30, then I'm probably still at that location.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks so much!! But I'm sorry I just a bit confused. What do r and mc refer to ?

Comment: `r` and `c` are aliases I assigned in the queries. (`r` is the inline view query, `c` is a reference to the `Comm`*whatever* table. The lack of a primary key or unique key is problematic for a `GROUP BY` operation, because that can collapse too many rows. Is the tuple `c (senderID, timestamp)` "unique enough", that we can collapse rows that have matching values for that? If the tuple m(visitorID, timestamp) isn't unique, we have potential for returning more than one row for `m` for a given row in `c`. (That's not necessarily invalid, depends on the specification that has to be met.)

Comment: And a correlated subquery isn't necessarily a bad thing, but one that gets called a bloatload of times, especially an inefficient one, will chew up clockcycles. Very often, an equivalent query without a correlated subquery  will beat the socks off of it, performance wise. But in some cases, a correlated subquery will be faster (that's usually when it's guaranteed to be executed a small number of times.)

Comment: @spencer7593 Oh I see.... thanks! unfortunately `c (senderID,timestamp)` is not unique at all. `m (visitorID,timestamp)` is however, unique.

Comment: The second to last query that includes the join to c may produce a result equivalent to the original query, except for the change to add the match `visitorID=senderID`.  This is a common pattern, find the latest/earliest/lowest out of a group of rows, and then return details of that row. The inline view with the GROUP BY to get the aggregate, and then a join back to the detail table. You'll find lots of questions, and lots of answers that use this pattern. (I corrected some mistakes in both of those queries, references to `c.` should have been `mc.`

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks so much for all the help!! The query is running for a while so I can't check it... but this was a lot of help in the right direction!

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the EXPLAIN output. (With the derived table, the explain will take longer... it has to materialize that query into a resultset, before it can run the EXPLAIN on the outer query.  You can run the inline view query standalone, and get an EXPLAIN on just that too.) You can add the information to the bottom of your question, under an `**EDIT**` heading... just don't change/rewrite the original question.

Comment: @spencer7593 I'm not sure if you still care to see, but I added the explain at the bottom!

Comment: The EXPLAIN output isn't looking as good as I expected; it looks like it's doing a full scan of `m`. That inline view is already doing most of the work. I see that MariaDB is creating an index on the derived table. (That doesn't happen on older versions of MySQL.) I think we'd really like to see the derived table being used as the "driver" for the join, with lookups to `m` using the index containing both visitorID and timestamp (showing `ref` as type for `m` and `ALL` for type on `<derived2>`.